# Decode hash sha256 encryption, knowing the salt

Tags: php, authentication, sha256, password-encryption

I'm making a login system for a web application. To store passwords in the DB, I'm encrypting passwords using sha256 as follows:

```
$salt ="sometext";
$escapedPW="userpass";
$saltedPW =  $escapedPW . $salt;
$hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);
echo "<center>".$hashedPW."</center>";
```

In the database I am storing the user, the user's password and the salt used to make hash and validate the user's  login. Right now I'm doing the functionality to send to the user an email with your password, but when the user receives the email, since is stored in sha256 encrypted password, the user receives a long string and not the password that the user is supposed to know.

My question is there any way that I can send you the actual user password and non the password encryption, ie, there is some way to do the reverse of sha256 if I know the salt?. If not possible, what method of encryption is recommended for you to complete the reverse of the encryption key and send the actual password to the user in an email.

Comment: The whole point of a hash is that you can't reverse it to get the original value; nor should you send the original password to the user who's forgotten it - you send them a one-time, time-limited link to reset their password

Comment: A hash is supposed to be irreversible (in an ideal world, at least). If you are basing your password recovery system on reversing your own hashes, you should rethink what you are doing. You are basically trying to hack yourself. +1 to the question, though, as other people may have the same doubt, and your question is quite useful.

Comment: @Renan Not necessarily, the user must be in the DB, and the password is sent to the user's personal email.

Comment: What Mark and I are trying to say is that you use a hash when you want to encrypt a piece of data in such a way that it should never be decrypted. You then store the result. If you hash another piece of data and get the same result, then it is **very probably** equal to the original data you first hashed. That's how hash authentication works. The point is that if a hacker makes a copy of your database, he won't be able to reverse the users' passwords from the hashes. There are ways to do it, but you're at least making it harder for the script kiddies.

Comment: @MarkBaker how safe is to send the user a random password, so that he can make login and then you can update your password?

Comment: @franvergara66 it's as safe as the user's email account is safe. If you do that and someone steals the user's random password, at least you can be sure that you are not the weak link in the security chain.

Comment: You don't send users a random password; you send them a one-time token in a password reset link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of your question, reversing the hash is not really an option.

What you can do however, and this is what everybody else does as well. In your registration code (ex. register.php) which your form post to you can make the PHP script send the password in an email and then encrypt it and store it in the database.

I suppose you have a registration form of some kind, and that form supposedly posts the new users details to another (or the same) php script, doesn't it?

For example if my form said something like `<form method="post" action="register.php">`

And in `register.php` I would then have something like

```
<?php
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); /*cleartext*/
$email    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

mail($email,"New account","Your username \"$username\" and your password is \"$password\"");

$salt ="sometext";
$escapedPW="userpass";
$saltedPW =  $escapedPW . $salt;
$hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ($username, $hashedPW, $email)")
```

Some rough example code. I hope it helps!

Comment: The pleasure is all mine :)

Answer (score 5):

You should NEVER send plaintext passwords via email. Rather, send a time-limited, single-use "reset password" link, as suggested in the comments.

You should *not* use a simple hash as suggested by @Henrik.  Use a standard adjustable-work password KDF (PBKDF2,bcrypt,scrypt)

If you can use PHP 5.5, use the [standard password hashing functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.password.php).  There are hosts which do support PHP 5.5, but you have to look for them and ask for it.

There are many places on the web that explain how to do it correctly (e.g. https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAppSec/Secure_Coding_Guidelines#Authentication) and many that explain how to do it incorrectly. PLEASE take some time to research this before you decide to roll your own authentication system.

Comment: Adding https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat to PHP 5.3.7 is easier than I previously thought - probably easier than moving to a PHP 5.5 host.